Odoo 17: UI does not allow for the creation/management of databases
I have installed Odoo 17 with PostgreSQL and it is working fine but when I try to create new database using Manage Databases nothing happens and the database creation form doesn't show.
and when I open web developer tools in the browser I get these errors:
This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “<!DOCTYPE html>”.

manager
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dist/dom/data.js”. manager:8:65

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dist/dom/event-handler.js”. manager:9:74

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dist/dom/manipulator.js”. manager:10:72

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dist/dom/selector-engine.js”. manager:11:76

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dist/base-component.js”. manager:12:71

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js”. manager:13:62

 Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/public/database_manager.js”.   

here is .config file:
[options]
addons_path = D:\program files\odoo17\server\odoo\addons

admin_passwd = 123

bin_path = D:\Program Files\odoo17\thirdparty 

csv_internal_sep = ,

data_dir = D:\Program Files\odoo17\sessions

db_host = localhost

db_maxconn = 64

db_maxconn_gevent = False

db_password = 123

db_port = 5432 


Please verify if you have set any db_name parameter inside .conf file .

@Yassir Irfan I checked I have db_name = odoo17 inside server/odoo.config

Please remove the db_name parameter from .conf and restart our odoo, by mentioning db_name = odoo17 odoo will choose the database odoo17 by default and it will prevent you from loading the /web/database/manager and /web/database/selector endpoints.

thanks for for your answer I tried removing db_name but still the same issue whenever I click any button like create database or restore database  or set master password nothing happens, is the reason that I am using community version ?

Do you see any error after creating database? If not after removing the .conf parameter you must restart your odoo, once its done you would be able to see them.

still the same thing after restarting odoo also there is no error because when I click create database button nothing happens, but I opened web developer tools I found there are several errors this error is one of them Loading failed for the 
Could you please share your .conf file parameters along with the question?

I updated the question and added .conf
